# Should we still use EMs for accessibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

All major browsers today use page zoom by default, as opposed to "text size". "text size" options are still there, but they are a bit more hidden [especially in Chrome and Firefox]. Given this fact, is there still a reason why EMs are advantageous over PX or %? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers indeed are capable of sizing pixels, and Zoom is now the more popular way which works well across browser - there is even a very simple fix the old IE6 behaviour of not being able to 'text size' (declare the original body size as a percentage - 100% will do - then fire away with pixels)

Remember too that if a user so desires, or needs to, they can set their own minimum **pixel** size so if they're basing their defaults on pixels why go through the nightmare of calculations..

IMHO pixels are perfect for text and borders (who needs to size a border lol..), always have been really.

`em` and `percentage` really are the same thing well they work identically, and their inheritance can be an absolute nightmare.. em's are great for widths and heights for a bit of fluidity

So no, I don't think we should still use them for text.. not that I ever did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the page-zoom feature turned off, most major browsers these days are capable of resizing text in *px* units. I think it was IE6 and under that was not capable of resizing px-based text.

I prefer specifying sizes in px just because I think it's easier than working off "relative" sizes.